# Set Date in a single line

Tags: java, date, calendar

According to the Java API, the constructor `Date(year, month, day)` is deprecated. I know that I can replace it with the following code:

```
Calendar myCal = Calendar.getInstance();
myCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, theYear);
myCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, theMonth);
myCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, theDay);
Date theDate = myCal.getTime();
```

However, I would like something shorter to replace it with (ideally one to two lines).

Comment: FYI: The terrible `Calendar` class is now supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). For a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone, use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You could use [`new GregorianCalendar(theYear, theMonth, theDay)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html)`.getTime()`:

> `public GregorianCalendar(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)`
>
> Constructs a GregorianCalendar with the given date set in the default time zone with the default locale.

Comment: I believe this is the "official Java correct answer" of how you are supposed to do it. Personally I rately have year, month and day in three fields like that, I usually have some form of string, so I use SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: Remember that January is 0, not 1. Or use Calendar constants: Calendar.JANUARY, etc.

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak good tip. It really is some really sadistic stuff from Java. "Let's see, years, yep, they'll be base 1, days base 1.. but months.. mwhahaha! base ZERO!" How much time has been wasted finding this sort of bug in your code ?

Comment: @angryITguy Approx 5 mins. That is infact if you created a unit test

Answer (score 28):

You could use

```
new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyyMMdd" ).parse( "20100520" )
```

Comment: But he has `theYear`, `theMonth`, `theDay`. Do you suggest he converts those to strings, and then concatenates them?

Comment: It should be mentioned that SimpleDateFormat isn't thread safe

Comment: @doublep SimpleDateFormat itself, if called by multiple threads the results are unpredictable - something I spend hours to fix it.

Comment: @stacker Are you sure? I thought it was only shared instances of SimpleDateFormat - not the class itself.  You're saying the class has static state?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe in that you cannot create a single instance, use it from two different threads that may execute simultaneously, and be confident that it will work. But I don't think there's any risk in creating an instance within a function and using it, as that instance would then only be used by the one thread. If I'm missing something here, feel free to correct me, but I've never observed a problem with such usage.

Comment: But tangens is creating a new SimpleDateFormat each time, so it's not being shared by different threads.

Comment: @stacker: An instance of `SimpleDataTime` is not thread safe, but the class certainly is. Instantiating a new copy on a thread and using that (as in the example) will never be a problem even with multiple threads executing it concurrently - each thread will have their own copy. This may not be the most efficient or correct answer for the question, however, but for other reasons.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, next time I first think.

Comment: Not a real one-liner because we need to wrap it inside a `try catch()` block.

Answer (score 14):

This is yet another reason to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateMidnight.html)

```
new DateMidnight(2010, 3, 5)
```

---

DateMidnight is now deprecated but the same effect can be achieved with Joda Time `DateTime`

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2010, 3, 5, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Introducing a dependency of a third party library for such a simple thing seems like an overkill.

Comment: @aioobe it might seem like overkill, but if there wasn't a use for it, it would have never been created.  Joda Time is not only easier to use (IMO), it is also much more efficient if you are creating many calendars or datetime objects.

Comment: This constructor does not exist for DateTime.  Please add 0 - fields for hour, minute, second, millisecond.

Comment: +1 for Joda Time - one of the most useful add-ons you can put in a java project.  Java is freaking mess anyway - third party libraries are what make it still usable (you probably use JQuery in your javascript, right?).

Comment: The “midnight” related classes in Joda-Time were all deprecated, replaced by [`LocalDate::toDateTimeAtStartOfDay`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#toDateTimeAtStartOfDay--). Also, the Joda-Time project is now in maintenance-mode with its team advising migration to the *java.time* classes.

Answer (score 10):

Calendar has a [set()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int,%20int,%20int)) method that can set the year, month, and day-of-month in one call:

```
myCal.set( theYear, theMonth, theDay );
```

Answer (score 7):

Why don't you just write a simple utility method:

```
public final class DateUtils {
    private DateUtils() {
    }

    public static Calendar calendarFor(int year, int month, int day) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        return cal;
    }

    // ... maybe other utility methods
}
```

And then call that everywhere in the rest of your code:

```
Calendar cal = DateUtils.calendarFor(2010, Calendar.MAY, 21);
```

Comment: I do like the simplicity of this answer. Very readable and reusable.

Comment: the method .set(int year, int month, int year) would avoid a lot of lines of code

Answer (score 7):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.of( 2015 , Month.JUNE , 7 )  // Using handy `Month` enum.
```

…or…

```
LocalDate.of( 2015 , 6 , 7 )  // Sensible numbering, 1-12 for January to December.
```

## java.time

The java.time framework built into Java 8 and later supplants the troublesome old classes, java.util.Date/.Calendar.

The java.time classes use [immutable objects](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). So they are inherently thread-safe. You will have none of the [thread-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) problems mentioned on the other answers.

### `LocalDate`

This framework included a class for date-only objects without any time-of-day or time zone, [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html). Note that a time zone (`ZoneId`) is necessary to determine a date.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );
```

You can instantiate for a specific date. Note that month number is a sensible range of 1-12 unlike the old classes.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2015 , 6 , 7 );
```

Or use the enum, [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html).

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2015 , Month.JUNE , 7 );
```

## Convert

Best to avoid the old date-time classes. But if you must, you can convert. Call new methods added to the old classes to facilitate conversions.

In this case we need to specify a time-of-day to go along with our date-only value, to be combined for a `java.util.Date` object. First moment of the day likely makes sense. Let java.time determine the time of that first moment as it is not always `00:00:00.0`.

We also need to specify a time zone, as the date varies by time zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId = zoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = localDate.atStartOfDay( zoneId );
```

An `Instant` is a basic class in java.time, representing a moment on the timeline in UTC. Feed an `Instant` to static method on Date to convert.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
java.util.Date utilDate = java.util.Date.from( instant );
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
Date date = new DateTime(2014, 6, 20, 0, 0).toDate();
```

DateTime is from Joda.org  https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html

Answer (score 2):

Use the constructor `Date(year,month,date)` in Java 8 it is deprecated:

```
Date date = new Date(1990, 10, 26, 0, 0);
```

The best way is to use `SimpleDateFormat`

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = format.parse("26/10/1985");
```

you need to import `import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;`