# How to initialise a variable of type Date in Java

Tags: java

Let say I have a very simple class with a date field like the following. How can I create its object?

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Test {
    public Test(Date date) {
        System.out.println("The date is " + date);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t1 = new Test(new Date());                        // This is working
    Test t2 = new Test(Sat Mar 03 00:43:32 GMT 2018);      // Not working
    Test t3 = new Test("Sat Mar 03 00:43:32 GMT 2018");    // Not working
    }
}
```

Even if I give the date in the same format like new Date() is providing, I still get an error. Why?

How can I pass a date which is acceptable to variable date?

UPDATE: The following is what I got working using a deprecated method. Any improvement?

```
    import java.util.Date;
    public class Test1 {
     public Test1(Date date) {
     System.out.println("The date is " + date);
     }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
     Test1 t1 = new Test1(new Date(118, 01, 03)); // This is working
     }
    }
```

Here is a bit better way that is working but still not good enough

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

    public class Test1 {

     public Test1(Date date) {
       System.out.println("The date is " + date);
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
      DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");


     try {
      Test1 t2 = new Test1(df.parse("02/02/2018")); // This is working
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println(e);
     }

     }
    }
```

Comment: see the documentation on the available constructors and methods --> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html . Once done, consider using `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime` instead of the Date type.

Comment: The "not working" examples, are simply not valid Java syntax.  You probably need to read a basic Java tutorial (or a text book) before you start writing Java code.  Unfortunately, programming is not like creative writing.  You can't just pull stuff out of the air ...

Comment: Note that `Date` is legacy, use `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime` instead.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877532/set-date-in-a-single-line

Make sure to use [Google](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=java+initialize+date+variable+%2B+stackoverflow&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A2000%2Ccd_max%3A2015&tbm=) before posting questions!

Comment: @Zabuza Actually, not `LocalDateTime` as that does *not* represent a moment. The replacement for `java.util.Date` is `Instant`, a point on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Test` constructor takes an object of type `Date`.

If you want to pass it a `String`, then instantiate a `Date` from that, you should create an overloaded constructor which has a parameter of type `String`.

```
public Test(String dateString) {
    Date date = new Date(dateString);
    System.out.println("The date is " + date);
}
```

Note that Strings in Java are double quoted, as in `new Test("Quoted String")`. You cannot pass an unquoted String, as in your example `new Test(Unquoted String)`.

Comment: I don't think OP is trying to pass a String representation of date. He is conceptually unclear. Moreover String based date constructor is already deprecated

Comment: Thats how I thought it should be but the challenge is I have to have Date dateString as parameter not String dateString as parameter

Comment: You can "overload" Java constructors, which means you can create a second constructor which takes a String.

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The troublesome `java.util.Date` class has been supplanted in Java 8 and later by the `Instant` class. (*huge* improvement)

You need to pass a instance of this class (an object) to the constructor method of your class, or to a setter method on your class.

An `Instant` represents a point on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds. To capture the current moment, call `now`.

Class:

```
public class Test {
    Instant instant ;
    public Test( Instant instantArg ) {
        this.instant = instantArg ;
        System.out.println( "The instant is " + this.instant.toString() );
    }
    // Add optional setter method if you desire. 
}
```

Usage:

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
Test test = new Test( instant ) ;
```

Or,

```
Test test = new Test() ;
test.setInstant( instant ) ;
```

Other avenues include Factory Method or a Builder. But look at those later, after gain more experience.

You might want to specify a date-time in a certain time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 12 , 34 ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( “Pacific/Auckland” ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;  // Adjust from other zone to UTC. Same moment, different wall-clock time.
Test test = new Test( instant ) ;
```

### Smart Objects versus Dumb Strings

Do not conflate a date-time object with a String representing its value. A date-time object such as `Instant` is not a String, though it can generate a String and it can parse a string.

```
String s = instant.toString() ;  // Generate a String in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

> 2018-12-17T18:00Z

And…

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( “2018-12-17T18:00Z” ) ;
```

You could add additional constructors or setter methods to accept such strings to be parsed into a date-time object. But generally it is better for your class to *not* take on responsibility for parsing with all the issues/problems that brings. I would place responsibility for instantiating the necessary `Instant` object onto the shoulders of the calling programmer.

By the way, you may notice that the *java.time* classes do not use constructors. The use static factory methods instead, such as `now`, `of`, `from`, and `parse`.

Comment: thanks. In my second attempt do you suggest I replace DateFormat with Instant?